# RXJS: Combining observables to emit in order

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have three observable ob1, ob2, ob2 all of them are API calls, I need them to be executed in order and the values to be emitted as an array and if there is any error I want the error to be caught in catchError and stop making further api calls, For example:

```
someCombine(ob1, ob2.pipe(tap(val=> doSomething)), ob3.pipe(tap(val=> 
doSomething))).pipe(catchError((err)=> of(err))).subscribe(combinedVal=>{
if(err) {
processErr
} 
else 
doSomething
});
```

I've tried using zip

```
 zip(ob1, ob2.pipe(tap(val=> doSomething)), ob3.pipe(tap(val=> 
    doSomething))).pipe(catchError((err)=> of(err))).subscribe(combinedVal=>{
    if(err) {
    processErr
    } 
    else 
    doSomething
    });
```

but zip will start next observable before completion of first one, I've tried concat

```
  concat(ob1, ob2.pipe(tap(val=> doSomething)), ob3.pipe(tap(val=> 
    doSomething))).pipe(catchError((err)=> of(err))).subscribe(combinedVal=>{
    if(err) {
    processErr
    } 
    else 
    doSomething
    });
```

but the values are being emitted separately for every individual observable completion.

How can I handle this scenario.

Comment: concat(...).pipe(bufferCount(3))

Comment: concat(...).pipe(toArray())

Answer (score 0):

something like this, I think:

```js
import { tap, delay, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of, throwError, combineLatest } from 'rxjs';


// this is just to simulate the requests
const ob1$ = of('ob1').pipe(delay(5000)),
      ob2$ = of('ob2').pipe(delay(1000)),
      ob3$ = of('ob3').pipe(delay(3000));


// abstract to reuse, since we'll catch for each observable
const handleError = (err) => {
  // process error
  console.log('process error', err);
  return throwError(err);
};

const doSomething = (val) => {
  // do something
  console.log('do something', val);
};


combineLatest(
  ob1$.pipe(catchError(handleError), tap(doSomething)),
  ob2$.pipe(catchError(handleError), tap(doSomething)),
  ob3$.pipe(catchError(handleError), tap(doSomething))
).subscribe(value => console.log(value));

// value = ["ob1", "ob2", "ob3"].
// Only emits when/if all 3 observables emit/complete.
```

I realize it's not EXACTLY what you asked for, since the requests are made simultaneously and emit in whatever order they can, but the resulting array will be properly ordered and only emit at the end. Each observable will trigger its own `tap` or `catchError`. Unless your use case is very particular, this should be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

**bufferCount**
`bufferCount` will emit the last x number of emits so if you know you have 3 api requests you have 3 emits after concating you can use `bufferCount(3)`

```js
const { of, concat, operators: { delay, bufferCount } } = rxjs;

const ob1$ = of ('ob1').pipe(delay(5000)),
  ob2$ = of ('ob2').pipe(delay(1000)),
  ob3$ = of ('ob3').pipe(delay(3000));

concat(ob1$, ob2$, ob3$).pipe(bufferCount(3)).subscribe({
  next: next => console.dir(next) // ['ob1', 'ob2', 'ob3]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.5.3/dist/global/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

--or--

**custom pipe**
This `drain` pipe operator will emit once the source observable completes and emits all of the emits at once so after contacted you can get all the results at the end and it will handle any number of emits.

```js
const { of, concat, Subscriber, operators: { delay } } = rxjs;

class DrainSubscriber extends Subscriber {
 constructor(destination) {
    super(destination);
    this.result = [];
  }
  _next(value) {
    this.result.push(value);
  }
  _complete() {
   this.destination.next(this.result);
    super._complete();
  }
}

class DrainOperator {
 call(subscriber, source) {
   return source.subscribe(new DrainSubscriber(subscriber));
  }
}

function drain() {
 return (source) => source.lift(new DrainOperator());
}

const ob1$ = of ('ob1').pipe(delay(5000)),
  ob2$ = of ('ob2').pipe(delay(1000)),
  ob3$ = of ('ob3').pipe(delay(3000));

concat(ob1$, ob2$, ob3$).pipe(drain()).subscribe({
  next: next => console.dir(next) // ['ob1', 'ob2', 'ob3]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.5.3/dist/global/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

in TypeScript https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-1yrvm2-drain-operator?file=index.ts

--promise alt--

**promise based alt**

```js
const { of, concat, operators: { delay } } = rxjs;

const ob1$ = of('ob1').pipe(delay(5000)),
  ob2$ = of('ob2').pipe(delay(1000)),
  ob3$ = of('ob3').pipe(delay(3000));

async function resolve() {
  const res1 = await ob1$.toPromise();
  const res2 = await ob2$.toPromise();
  const res3 = await ob3$.toPromise();
  return [res1, res2, res3];
}

resolve().then(results => {
  console.dir(results); // ['ob1', 'ob2', 'ob3]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.5.3/dist/global/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```